# python manage.py syncdb not working

Tags: python, django-syncdb

C:\Users\acc\Desktop\coding>python manage.py syncdb

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "manage.py", line 10, in

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line
399, in execute_from_command_line

utility.execute()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line
392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242,
 in run_from_argv

```
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 280,
 in execute

```
translation.activate('en-us')
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation__init__.py", lin
e 130, in activate

return _trans.activate(language)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", l
ine 188, in activate

```
_active.value = translation(language)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", l
ine 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", l
ine 158, in _fetch

```
for appname in reversed(settings.INSTALLED_APPS):
```

TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence

please give me advice for removing this bug...

Comment: So, what is the value of INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman            
INSTALLED_APPS={
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',        
    'django.contrib.admindocs',


}

Answer (score 2):

You've made INSTALLED_APPS a set instead of a tuple. It should have parentheses, not curly brackets.